# rosjava_actionlib not build by gradle

Tags: ros, actionlib, build, rosjava-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello people!

I followed the instructions on [link](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html) to build the new ros_core with gradle. However, the package "rosjava_actionlib" is not built by gradle. When doing a "gradle install" in that folder, gradle keeps telling me, it can't find ":rosjava" in rosjava_actionlib.

Any suggestions?

**edit:**
ok, I found the file settings.gradle which has the following lines:

> // TODO(damonkohler): Enable these
> once actionlib is working again.

> //'rosjava_actionlib',
> 'rosjava_actionlib_tutorial'

I uncommented the line and added a "," appropriately but it seems, rosjava_actionlib is not working yet. Does anybody know when this will be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31174/rosjava_actionlib-not-build-by-gradle/) by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The existing implementation of actionlib will probably *not* be fixed to work with the most recent changes to rosjava. A new implementation will be started soon.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on 2012-04-25**:
sorry for the late answer, and thank you for this information! Could you tell me where to download the last working combination of rosjava, actionlib_java and android_gingerbread?

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-25**:
rosjava_core revision dc75590fbcc1 and android_core revision b5dcbe605d20 should probably work. You may have to go back or forward in time. The current documentation is not consistent with anything at that version, so be prepared for a challenge.

**Comment by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on 2012-04-26**:
With rosjava_core revision dc75590fbcc1 I had build errors. On http://answers.ros.org/question/29304/how-to-rosmake-rosjava-from-source I found the suggestion of using the 1084ec6c569c revision, which finally builds! When installing ros-electric, there is also a rosjava included - how old is that?

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-26**:
In a word, very.